# Docker RUN instruction to source bash profile

Tags: docker

I run some installation scripts via docker, they change ~/.bashrc but then I need to source it to use installed commands in RUN instructions below.

Tried obvious `RUN . ~/.bashrc` and got `/bin/sh: 13: /root/.bashrc: shopt: not found` error.

Tried `RUN . ~/.profile` and got `mesg: ttyname failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device`

**I do not want to use ENV instructions. The point of having external installation scripts is to use them in non-Docker environments, for example when running unit tests locally. ENV instructions would duplicate environment setup which is already done in installation scripts.**

Comment: Can you share the Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to set up shell dotfiles in Docker.  Many typical paths do not run them at all; for example

```
# In a Dockerfile
CMD ["some", "command", "here"]

# From the command line
docker run myimage some command here
```

The Docker environment is, fundamentally, different from a standalone Linux system; in addition to shell dotfiles, "home directory" isn't really a Docker concept, and if you have a multi-part process, on Docker it's standard to run each part in a separate container, but on standalone Linux you could use the init system to keep all of the parts running together.  If you're expecting things to work exactly the same with exactly the same installation scripts, a virtual machine would be a better technological match for what you're attempting.

("Inappropriate ioctl for device" also suggests that there are things in the dotfiles that strongly expect to be run from an actual terminal, which you don't necessarily have at `docker build` time.)

My generic advice here is:

1. If possible, install things in the "system" directories within the image and avoid needing custom environment variable settings.  (Don't use a version manager like nvm or rvm; don't use a Python virtual environment.)
2. If you do have to set environment variables, `ENV` is the way to do it.
3. If you really can't do either of the above, you can set environment variables in an `ENTRYPOINT` script before launching the main process; but if it's important to you that variables show up in `docker inspect` or `docker exec` shells, they won't be set there.

(Also remember that each `RUN` command launches a new container with a totally new shell environment.  You can `RUN . .profile; foo`, but the environment variable settings won't carry through to the next `RUN` line.)

Comment: Does this mean that with Docker whatever I install via convenient installation scripts (e.g. nvm: curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash) I have to follow-up with a bunch of ENV instructions for installed stuff to be available in next RUNs? This seems like an extreme inconvenience to me.

Comment: Like I said, don't use nvm; just use an appropriate `node:whatever` base image.

Comment: I can't use a different image for my current task. But that is not the point. What I want to achieve is to have an install.sh script for all node-related stuff. That script will be run directly by devs who work with me & run via Docker ("RUN ./install.sh") in CI and production. If I would use a different image, script and image paths would diverge.